# tick labels style overwrites extra tick label style

Tags: pgfplots

[image]

For reasons, I need to move a tick label slightly to the right. Additionally I want to add an extra tick label at the zero of a function. However, the style chosen for the x label overwrites the style chosen for the extra tick label. Is this intended?  I want the extra tick label to be directly below the tick

MWE( though I can't format it properly).

```
\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{tikz} \usepackage{pgfplots}\begin{document}\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis} [domain=0:1,
restrict y to domain= -1:1,
xmax=1.1, 
axis x line= middle, 
axis y line = left,
xtick={1},
x tick label style={anchor=north west},
xlabel =$s$, 
extra x ticks={0.25},    
every extra x tick/.style={ anchor=center},
extra x tick label={$s_c$},
no markers,]\addplot (x,x-0.25);\end{axis}\end{tikzpicture}\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`every x tick style` is admittedly a little confusing since it is meant to be a generic key to access extra ticks AND tick labels as if you are defining a new axis. I don't know if this is the official point of view but following can say more than I can summarize

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
domain=0:1,
restrict y to domain= -1:1,
xmax=1.1, 
axis x line= middle, 
axis y line = left,
xtick={1},
x tick label style={anchor=north west},
xlabel =$s$, 
extra x ticks={0.25},
extra x tick label={$s_c$},
extra x tick style={grid=major,xticklabel style={anchor=north,red}},
no markers,
]\addplot (x,x-0.25);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 `extra x tick style={grid=major,xticklabel style={anchor=north,red}}` saved my day! I did not think that `xticklabel style` is necesarry and only used `extra x tick style={}`.